# NodeJS / jQuery - Poll notifications API

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have the following JSON data in an API:

```
[
   {
      notification: "'James' has created a new user. This requires
      approval",
      read: null
   }
]
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/notifications",

    success: function(data) {
    counterText = 0;
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {

      if(value.read == 0 || value.read == null)
      {
          var theCounter = parseInt($('.counter').text());
          counterText += theCounter += 1;
      }
   });
   $('.counter').text(counterText);
   }
});
```

The problem is that this only works when someone refreshes the browser. I am using Socket.io in order to do real-time notifications, however, instead of each notification coming in, I just ideally need to update this code each time a socket comes in. For example, an event called "Ping"

```
socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\Ping", function(message) {
  $.toast({
    heading: 'Information',
    text: message.data.message,
    icon: 'info',
    loader: false,        // Change it to false to disable loader
    loaderBg: '#9EC600'  // To change the background
 });
});
```

There are, however, a lot of events so I don't really want to have to update on each on. Ideally, I would like instant polling on this file so that notifications can updated immediately without the need of refreshing the browser.

Comment: Trying to identify the question... Does your socket code snippet work? You say "ideally need to update this code each time a socket comes in" but also "I don't really want to have to update on each on" (sic). Those sound like opposing goals. Are you looking for advice on the tradeoffs between those two choices? Or are you looking for ideas on performance optimizations like concurrent processing and event buffering? If the latter, you may wish to have a look at web workers and RxJS.

Comment: @Will Sorry for the confusion. Basically, I want to do polling so that I can call the API and update the notification system.. Say every minute or so. I don't mind doing it through socket.io but I'm confused to how this would be done using socket.io without having to call a function in each of the sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase, it sounds like you'd like to add a polling mechanism to your AJAX approach. (Sockets can have advantages such as reduced latency, but they can be slightly more complex, so I understand why you may not want to try them at this time.) All your current AJAX code lacks is really just a mechanism to make continual requests on an interval. You can do that with:

```
var polling = true;
var period = 60 * 1000; // every 60 seconds
var interval = polling && setInterval(function() {
  if (polling) {
    $.ajax({
      ... // existing ajax call here
    });
  } else {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
}, period);

// Later, if you want to stop polling, you can:
polling = false;

// ...or even just:
if (interval) {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! But will this drag the server down at all? I'm worried making so many requests will have a negative impact on things

Comment: You're welcome. Whether it "drags down" the server depends on the server implementation. If this behavior is the requirement, then the server would ideally be tested and optimized to account for this request pattern. Servers can be optimized for less frequent polling (like this), for frequent instant push (like websockets), or other patterns. The better you know how your application will be used by people and accessed over networks, the better you can optimize.